# Django SwampDragon : KeyError 'channel'

Tags: python, django, swampdragon

I have searched everywhere for a solution on this and after a long time searching I still have no answer.

I am using Django 1.7 over Swampdragon 0.4.2. I get this exception every random period of time.

```
WebSocket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sockjs/tornado/transports/websocket.py", line 60, in on_message
    self.session.on_messages(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sockjs/tornado/session.py", line 418, in on_messages
    self.conn.on_message(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swampdragon/connections/sockjs_connection.py", line 90, in on_message
    raise e
KeyError: 'channel'

Request repr(): unavailable
```

Anybody has any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a really long time I finally debugged the SwampDragon code and found that the problem was that you need to send channel name on unsubscribe as well (from the client).